# "In what sense": "in what way" or "what does it mean"?

Tags: usage

I have asked an Isreali guy "You said the video was compelling. In what sense?" He said, "emotionally and in that it points out the problems with these laws."

Here I suppose the "in what sense" was interpreted as "in what way".

However, when I saw the definition of "as in", I saw the following:
As in: (idiomatic, conjunctive) In the sense of.

E.g. "bow" as in the weapon, not the front of a ship

Here I think "in the sense of" is like "having the meaning of", although I am not sure.

And so when I asked "in what sense", what I meant was, "what do you mean by using that word" "what does the word that you used mean?"

So what's the correct understanding of "in what sense" "in the sense of"? Does it mean "in what way", "what does it mean", or both?

Sorry if this sounds a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate phrases in your question.

The first is: **in what sense** which, as you correctly surmise, is another way of saying **in what way**.

The second is: **as in**, a phrase that is generally used to introduce an example or category, which you illustrate correctly.

Most of the time, instead of saying **as in**, you might say **referring to, signifying** or **meaning**.

So you might say to someone, I am interested in the origins of the word **sow** as in (meaning, referring to) seeds rather than **sew** (referring to, signifying) as in clothes.

Comment: I can understand. However, if "as in" is "in the sense of", doesn't it mean that "as in" is like the answer to "in what sense"? That's what I am confused about.

Comment: If somebody asked you:**In what sense do you mean sanction?** You might reply: **as in punish, not permit**. **In what sense** is a question. **As in** is used to introduce the answer.